# 'undefined is not an object' in karma/jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following simple unit test:

```
describe('SyncController', function() {
  var controller,
      deferredRecount,
      pouchdbServiceMock;

  beforeEach(module('inspector'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $q, $scope) {
    deferredRecount = $q.defer();

    pouchdbServiceMock = {
      getRecordCounts: jasmine.createSpy('getRecordCounts spy').and.returnValue(deferredRecount.promise)
    };

    controller = $controller('SyncController', {
      '$scope': $scope,
      'pouchdbService': pouchdbServiceMock
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {  
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    controller.recount();
  }));

  describe('recount', function() {
    it('should call getRecordCounts on pouchdbService', function() {
      expect(pouchdbServiceMock.getRecordCounts).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Calling `pouchdbServiceMock.getRecordCounts` in the last `describe` block generates an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pouchdbServiceMock.getRecordCounts') in unit-tests/sync.controller.tests.js (line 29)
```

However `pouchdbServiceMock` is assigned in the second `beforeEach` block. What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to set the beforeEach statements inside the second describe.

Comment: Did not help. The same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the second beforeEach block had an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
```

So it did not initialized the variable `pouchdbServiceMock`. I rewrote the block a little bit:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $q, $rootScope) {
    deferredRecount = $q.defer();
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    pouchdbServiceMock = {
      getRecordCounts: jasmine.createSpy('getRecordCounts spy').and.returnValue(deferredRecount.promise)
    };

    controller = $controller('inspector.SyncController', {
      '$scope': scope,
      'pouchdbService': pouchdbServiceMock
    });
  }));
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of pouchdbServiceMock is a bit odd, at least from my experience doing tests in the last year.

```
pouchdbServiceMock = jasmine.createSpy('getRecordCounts', ['getRecordCounts']);
pouchdbServiceMock.getRecordCounts.and.returnValue(deferredRecount.promise);
$provide.value('pouchdbService', pouchdbServiceMock);
```

That's how I would structure it. Try it out, see if works.